# Switching between JDeveloper versions

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We have developed a product using JDeveloper 11.1.2.x but we need to downgrade to JDeveloper 11.1.1.6. Is there any tool for the same or easier method then manually redesigning entire product ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a tool to do that. Why would you want to downgrade?

Comment: Due to internal policies we had to downgrade. Is there any quick way to downgrade ?

Comment: See this link, maybe it helps: http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/case-study-backporting-a-jdeveloper-project-from11gr2-to-11gr1/

Answer (score 0):

Suresh there is no tool to do that and even beyond that there is more that likely no way to change your code into 11.1.1.6 automatically due to changes in the way the code is generated.

Your best bet is going to be create a new application and project in jdeveloper 11.1.1.6 that has the same name and then move the code besides the .jpr and the .jws file which contains the  version metadata in it.

Next you will have to make sure it compiles which might present some problems and even beyond that there are 100's of bug fixes and plenty changes around ADF mobile and ADF BC. There are also new sets of functions such as ADF essentials.

[What's changed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/jdev-11gr2-nf-404365.html)